# How do I insert data into access table from another access table using a query?

Tags: java, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to use query to insert the entirety of one table into another (so no where clause). I am using java (exlipse). I want to insert data into JJ from ENTER
My code:
Edit: the ur variable is set at an earlier point so I don't have to type it a million times.

```
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(ur);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO JJ ( Date, Account, Amount, DrCr )"
                + "SELECT ENTER.Date, ENTER.Account, ENTER.Amount, ENTER.DrCr"
                + "FROM ENTER;";
```

I'm getting the error:
CAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT unexpected token: ; in statement [INSERT INTO JJ ( Date, Account, Amount, DrCr )SELECT ENTER.Date, ENTER.Account, ENTER.Amount, ENTER.DrCrFROM ENTER;]
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatemen

Comment: The error message is "unexpected token: ;". Did you try to remove the semicolon?

Comment: Yes I did. I had a working querry that was in access and just copy-paste. My issue is resolved though I have no idea what the issue was. The error I got when the semicolon was "Unexpected end of statement"